# How to make pipe always work, instead of check changes?

Tags: angular, pipe

I have a pipe which finds all emoji names and replace them into the icon.
But the problem is that the pipe doesn't change the last character which was added until I type anything. For example (:heart_eyes:) last :heart_eyes: doesn't change before I type anything.
How to make the pipe works all the time, instead of waiting for some changes?

HTML:

```
<textarea matInput #newMessage color="primary" 
mwlTextInputElement
[formControl]="newMessageFormControl"
[value]="newMessageFormControl.value | q9Emoji"
></textarea>`


TS:
transform(value: any): any {
return this.replace(value);
}

replace(value) {
const emojisRegex = new RegExp(':(' + 
Object.keys(this.emojiObj).join('|') + '):', 'g');

return value.replace(emojisRegex, (match, text) => this.emojiService.unifiedToNative(this.emojiObj[text]));
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimum reproduction for this

Answer (score 2):

use the two-way binding instead [formControl], this returns a value on every character change and also you can use (keyup)="newMessage".

```
[(ngModel)]="newMessage"
```